# Print and combine contents from cell if other value of other cell is true

Tags: excel, bioinformatics, genetics

Been trying to figure this out for a while, hoping someone might have an idea or has come across something similar.

I currently have an excel sheet that shows a genetic sequence in Row 2 split into three letter codons within a cell which has a numerical identifier in Row 1. Below this are a number of samples (1 per row) which have been compared outside of excel to the sequence in Row 2. Where a letter matches the wildtype sequence in Row 2 it is represented by a period "." where it differs the identified mutation is displayed  instead.

What I would like to be able to do is go through this sheet on a row by row basis, identify those mutations that exist and then print/pipe the numerical identifier in row 1 representing that column into another summary cell.

Ideally the final output would be a summary row for each sample containing the the location of each mutation identified.

[Wildtype sequence and mutation sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L8hy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done but I would strongly recommend not do it this way.

- Excel is a horrible way of handling such data.
- Excel is great for other purposes, such as accounting, but not for biological data.

But back to your your question.

Add the end of your table, after all the samples, add in column B the following formula

```
=IF(B4<>"…", B$2 & ";","")
```

It will check for each position if the sample's sequence is `...` and if not it will take the position from row 2 (and append a semi-colon to it) (the `$` makes sure it's always the 2nd row). Copy&paste this formula in all columns where you have a codon and in as many rows as you have samples.

Next you want to join the all those results. Add one of the following formulas to column A, next to the previous formula.

```
CONCATENATE(B100, B101, B102)
```

or
    B100 & B101 & B102
you need to add all other cells as well to the formula (another reason why Excel is not the right tool here).

The output would then be for your sample 1:

> 802;

if you have multiple mutations it would be something like

> 301;410;

Of course this can be done with VBA for Excel as well, but again this is not the right tool to do it. It would make more sense to handle and manipulate the data in a language where there are already packages for handling biological data and then just write it back to an Excel sheet.